# How to set initial state from local storage in next js?

Tags: next.js, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I want to get value from local storage in next js. It should look some thing like this in next js. But this don't work. How to do it?

```
const initialState = {
  language: {
    lang: "eng",
    iconPath: "/imgFolder1/usaIcon.png",
    languageFullEng: "English",
    languageFullHeb: "אנגלית",
  },
};

const setInitialLanguage = () => {
  const language = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("language"));
  if (language) {
    return language;
  } else {
    return initialState;
  }
};

const languageSlice = createSlice({
  name: "language",
  initialState: setInitialLanguage(),
  reducers: {
    setLanguage: (state, action) => {
      state.language = action.payload;
      localStorage.setItem("language", JSON.stringify(state));
    },
  },
});

export const { setLanguage } = languageSlice.actions;
export default languageSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: You should consider using cookies instead of local storage. Cookies can be accessed from both server and client.